# How can I copy a string into a char array pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization, string-literals

I am new to C and inherited some legacy code that I am trying to understand and make some improvements to. I need to add elements to a char array pointer, but I can't figure out the correct syntax. In the example below, I want to append a to args.

```
char *a = "A";
char *args[10] = {"hello","hi","bye",NULL};
```

I'm sure the answer is really obvious to someone with more experience in C. Any help/pointers (no pun intended!) would be greatly appreciated!

I tried using strcat like below, but the program hangs.

```
strcat(*args,a);
```

I am hoping to get a result where `args = {"hello","hi","bye","A",NULL};`.

Comment: `args[3] = a;` `args[4] = null;`.

Comment: ... or `args[4] = NULL;`.

Comment: or `args[3] = a;` since the rest of the array is already nulled

Comment: Or simply args[3] = "A";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either include the pointer `a` as an initializer in the array declaration like

```
char *a = "A";
char *args[10] = {"hello","hi","bye", a, NULL};
```

or

```
char *args[10] = { "hello","hi","bye", a };
```

Or after the array declaration for example write

```
char **p = args;
while ( *p ) ++p;
*p = a;
```

If in some part of the program you are not sure whether the array contains a slot with a null pointer then you can write

```
char **p = args;
while ( p != args + 10 && *p ) ++p;
if ( p != args + 10 ) *p = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

you simply assign to the array index:

```
args[3] = a;
args[4] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
strcat(*args,a);
```

This tries to append `"A"` to `"hello"` - but `"hello"` is a string literal and you should not try to alter string literals. They are often stored in read-only memory so you can get strange, undefined, behavior if you do try that.

The proper way to append it to the `char` pointer array is demonstrated by Vlad and Barmar. Here's another demonstrative program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// print the strings in the NULL terminated char* array:
void print(char *argv[]) {
    for (; *argv; ++argv) {
        puts(*argv);
    }
    puts("---");
}

// Add a char* to the char* array:
void add(int argc, char *argv[], char *str) {
    // find the first char* pointing at NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i) {      // -1 to have room for NULL
        if (argv[i] == NULL) {
            argv[i] = str;
            argv[i + 1] = NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
}

#define SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof *(x))

int main(void) {
    char *a = "A";
    char *args[10] = {"hello", "hi", "bye", NULL};

    // strcat(*args,a); // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR

    print(args);  // hello hi bye

    add(SIZE(args), args, a);

    print(args);  // hello hi bye A
}
```